# Sound Recorder not playing back

Tags: storage

After recording several hours of music on my ZTE android phone , using the phone's mic placed next to a radio and utilizing the 'Sound Recorder' App , I tried to play it back later that day and got the error message "Unable to access storage space".
  I was using an SD card as storage so I switched to Phone Storage and got the same message.  Tried again using phone storage and was able to play back my recording.
  Seems to be an intermittent problem but I can't be sure.  I've done this before and never had this problem.  I hope this enough info because that pretty much explains the issue.  If there's anything else that's needed , please let me know.
  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
 Mike
```

Comment: You need to give more details before anyone can understand your problem. What app were you using to record the music, and what steps did you do to try to play it back?